# get user location using location flutter package

Tags: flutter, location

i want to get the user location in flutter using LOCATION PACKAGE, the problem here is i don't know how can i call my method inside my class widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}
class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
String error;
void getLocation() async {
var location = new Location();
try {
  await location.getLocation().then((onValue) {
    print(onValue.latitude.toString() + "," + onValue.longitude.toString());
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED')
    error = 'Permission denied';
  else if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK')
    error =
        'Permission denied - please ask the user to enable it from the app settings';
}
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('LOCATION'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
             // i want to call my method here 
           ],
          ),
        )));
 }
 }
```

Thank you guuuys,

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you want to do in column widget but if your print methods from try and catch works you can just assign values in there to strings.

So create two strings in your _LocationScrenState:

`String lat,long;`

And then instead of printing it in your catch and try:
`lat=onValue.latitude.toString();`
`long= onValue.longitude.toString();`

Then you can use those strings in your column.

Edit:

You can call your function
`getLocation();`
in initState. Just start typing initState in your
`_LocationScreenState`
and your IDE should provide you with the code to override initState which is the method executing only once when your widget is inserted to widget tree(means on the very beginning).

Edit2:
Ok so here is exact solution to your problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}
class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
String error;
**String lat,long;**
**@override
void initState() {
  getLocation();
  super.initState();
}**

void getLocation() async {
var location = new Location();
try {
  await location.getLocation().then((onValue) {
    print(onValue.latitude.toString() + "," +onValue.longitude.toString());
    **lat = onValue.latitude.toString();
    long = onValue.longitude.toString();**
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED')
    error = 'Permission denied';
  else if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK')
    error =
        'Permission denied - please ask the user to enable it from the app settings';
}
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Here. A I have highlighted added code with **. Then you can use lat and long string to do whatever you want with them in the column widget.

Comment: thanks sir for your answer, but i don't understand how can i modify the code using initState, could you please help me.

Comment: Alright then I advise you to read more on Widgets lifecycle but I will edit my answer with  exact solution to your problem